# map_dfr with a function and paste0

Tags: r, purrr

I have a function `reviews` and i want iterate the function parameters with map_dfr and paste 0 to change the input. so something like

```
got_reviews <- function(page) {
    
    ...
    
    return(reviews)
}

link <- "blah=?"
all_reviews <- map_dfr(seq(0,80, by = 10), got_reviews(paste0(link,.?.)))
```

i want the paste0 to loop the sequence but i don't know how to refer to it inside the map_dfr or if this is even possible. i thought of doing it with a for loop but from reading it was suggested to use map or lapply or slappy but i am not sure how to refer to the sequence in any of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `.x` with a lambda call (`~`)

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(seq(0,80, by = 10), ~ got_reviews(paste0(link,.x)))
```

---

Also, as `paste` is vectorized, there is no need to do this in a loop i.e. create the input with `paste0`, loop over the `vector`, with `map` and apply the `got_reviews`.  As there is only a single argument for the function, we don't need to specify the argument

```
map_dfr(paste0(link, seq(0, 80, by = 10)), got_reviews)
```

Comment: @sourlemonaid the tidyverse lambda is a compact option.  In `base R`, we use `function(x)` and in the newer versions `\(x)`